# 2006 Honda Civic Hybrid, error lights on dash, and codes

Tags: civic, obd-ii, hybrid

A few months ago, my Civic Hybrid started giving me issues.

When I start it in the morning, I have to hold the key for a few seconds before the engine catches. Once the engine is running, my IMA light, 12V battery light, Check Engine Light is on. Sometimes the D indicator is flashing.

After a while I've noticed that I have to let the car warm up (all of the lights I listed are still on). After it warms up, I turn the car off and start it again. It once again, takes a few seconds for the engine to catch. At this point, the lights are still on except the D light is no longer flashing. I let it run for another 10 minutes then turn the car off.

At this point I can hear a fan sound from my hybrid battery in the back. When I hear it shut off, I start the car. It starts fine. No delay. As if nothing is wrong. I drive my car to work (about 7 minutes) and its parked for 4.5 hours until i leave for lunch. Still starts fine. When I get off a few hours later, starts fine. Go home. Head out the next day, back to having issues.

I live in the Bahamas, so I can't take it to a dealer. I did a diagnostic scan and got codes P0A78, P0A3F, U0110.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you had the codes cleared and these came back, I think the last code is the most telling. It is "Lost communication with drive motor control module A". All three of them have to do with Motor A (and maybe that's all there is is motor A ... dunno). If the computer has lost comms with control module A, I'd suggest the control module is probably where the issue lies. I don't know enough about Hybrids to post authoritatively, though, so ... grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks. I'm purchasing a dc converter. I hope it works. If not, I'm selling.

Comment: I've even considered it being a simple fuse. My problem is that NO MECHANIC on this island is knowledgeable with civic hybrids. So I'm just using YouTube.